# How to package a NextJS App with Spring Boot Backend into the same WAR / JAR file?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, tomcat, next.js

I am building a NextJS app with a Spring Boot backend.

In addition to static pages, I have code in my NextJS app that pulls data from the Spring boot backend via API calls using the `getServerSideProps` method. For example:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const designations = await getDesignations();
  if (designations) {
    return {
      props: { designations },
    };
  }
}



  async function getDesignations() {
  console.log("Getting designations from server");
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("/web/designations");
    return {
      error: false,
      data: response.data,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      error: true,
      errorDetails: {
        code: error.code,
        description: "An unexpected error occurred",
      },
    };
  }
}
```

I have managed to build the app and test it locally by running the Spring Boot API separately on port 8080 and the NextJS app running separately on port 3000.

Now I would like to build and package both of these to one deployable unit, and would prefer to deploy on Tomcat.

As long as I was using `create-react-app` to build my react app, I was able to use the `frontend-maven-plugin` to build the react app and put it to Spring boot's `public` directory so that the react app could be served. This worked perfectly fine.

Now, the problem is in order to `getServerSideProps` to work in NextJS, I understand there must be a Node.js backend.

So, I am wondering how I can bundle my nextjs app in its current state with the spring boot backend and package it into the same WAR/JAR file so that I can ship and run it in one piece.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work without using the `getServerSideProps()` method. Instead, use a static html export to generate html instead of js in the build.

```
"scripts": {"build": "next build && next export"}
```

Use the above script for building. There's just a small catch too, it gives the web address ending with '.html'.
You can refer to the Next.js deployment documentation for more info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment) and for Static HTML Export [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export).